# Angle plane makes with semi-meridian on sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, curves

(doCarmo, Exercise 2, Sec. 2-5) Let $ \textbf{x}(\phi,\theta) = (\sin \theta \cos \phi, \sin \theta \sin \phi, \cos \theta)$ be a parametrisation of the unit sphere $S^2$. Let P be the plane $x=z\cot \alpha$, $0 < \alpha < \pi$, and $\beta$ be the acute angle which the curve $P \cap S^2$ makes with the semimeridian $\phi = \phi_0$. Compute $\cos \beta$.

I assumed the basis $\{{\textbf{x}_{\theta},\textbf{x}_{\phi}}\}$ and computed the components of the two curves in terms of these and used the standard formula for the inner product to get $$\cos \beta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\cot^2 \alpha + \cos^2 \phi_0}}.$$ Would just like to confirm the answer with someone else - thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Trying to check your result in alternate trig form

$$ \tan ^2 \beta = 1/ \tan ^2 \alpha + \cos ^2 \phi_0 ^2 $$

At equator meridian should cut great circle at complementary angles.

At max polar angle it should cut at angle  $\beta = \pi/2. $

Best way is to check by using Claraut's Law, not so sure/comfortable about notation..

$$  \sin \theta \sin \beta = ..\cos (\alpha).. $$

EDIT1:

I derived to obtain a result which in your nomenclature is:

$$ \tan \beta = \frac{ \cot \alpha \sin \theta - \cos \theta \sin \phi }{ \cos \phi} $$

It should be checked and perhaps be further simplified, using your given conditions by division

$$ \cot \alpha = \tan \theta \cos \phi $$

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I'm fairly new to this stuff so I had to graph this out to visualise. Allow me to make a rough translation of your assessment and perhaps you could tell me if this reflects accurately: Look at the case where the plane is cutting at an angle of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ (corresponding to $\alpha=\frac{\pi}{2}$), then $\beta$ should be $\frac{\pi}{2}$ but this violates the formula I gave. Is this correct?

Comment: Right, I think you need to check it out. A rough sketch even by hand is helpful in marking out all the 4 angles showing meridian cutting in between extreme positions of the great circle.